# What are the consequence of Snevily's conjecture to analytic number theory if really there is a connection between them?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, additive-combinatorics

[Snevily's conjecture](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/snevilys_conjecture#comment) it is an open conjecture in Group theory for non cyclic Group and it were proved  for abelian groups of prime order using a fairly standard application of the Alon-Tarsi polynomial technique .It states that:

**Snevily's conjecture**:
let $G$ be an abelian Group of odd order and let $A,B \subseteq G$ satisfy $|A|=|B|=k$  .Then the elements of $A$ and $B$ may be ordered $A=\{a_1\cdots a_k\}$ and $B=\{b_1\cdots b_k\}$ so that the sums $a_1+b_1,a_2+b_2,\cdots a_k+b_k$ are pairwise distinct .

its seems that conjecture has connection to analytic number theory such that , This conjecture  were proved for $\mathbb{Z_n}$ a subgroup of the multiplicative group of the field of order $2^{\phi(n)}$ with $\phi(n)$ is the Euler totiont function , Now my question here is :  What are the consequence  of Snevily's conjecture to analytic number theory if really there is a connection between them?

**Addedendum** :I have added [this paper](http://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0097316509000855?token=6CCF95B084D30798CC47C1753EFA160FD705D7289AED2DA9F1801E0A79E36E359BD2CCB20FA2FE12DBD7499F1BA8916F) entitled "Divisors of the number of Latin rectangles" just to  show the connection between latine square which it is the source of the titled conjecture  and number divisors (number theory) .This means probably we will have some consequence of the titled conjecture to analytic  number theory in the futur.

Comment: Can you make this more precise? Interesting isn't a well-defined term, and this may be too opinion based for it to attract good answers.

Comment: Is $k$ related to $G$ in some way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Snevily's conjecture was [proved in 2009](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11856-011-0040-6) by Bodan Arsovski. He was a [high-school student](https://www.imo-official.org/participant_r.aspx?id=9164) at the time.

I don't know of any consequences in analytic number theory. On the other hand, there are several papers before and after Arsovski's proof that connect Snevily's conjecture to other (combinatorial) group theoretic questions or discuss variations.

Comment: However my question would be close soon but I up vote to this answer because it will encourage me to do more research about  connection between that conjecture to analytic number theory ,When I checked the bounds of number of latice square which it is very hard to be computable I think we can write that bound using arithmitic functions